# Laravel API Route is not working in Postman

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create an API for my application But the API route not working. I have a route in routes/api.php also I have created a virtual hostname called `hotelplex.test`.

**app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php**

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::domain(env('API_DOMAIN'))
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

[image: View Code]

**.env**

```
API_DOMAIN = api.hotelplex.test
```

**routes\api.php**

```
Route::get('/guests', function() {

    $guest = [
        "name" => "Harshith"
];
    return $guest;
});
```

[image: View Code]

When I visit `api.hotelplex.dev/guests` using Postman its showing below response

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://api.hotelplex.dev/guests.
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

[image: View Response]

Comment: you said that you setup `hotelplex.test` but you are trying to get `hotelplex.dev` in Postman

Comment: yeah sorry but its not working in `hotelplex.test` also

Comment: wait i will upload the picture

Comment: I just reuploaded reponse for `hotelplex.test` check now

Comment: what do you get in Postman console or when you visit it with browser?

Comment: When I visit url using chrome it's showing me. `This site can’t be reached api.hotelplex.test’s server IP address could not be found.`

Comment: Have you tried with other browser? Do you get same error? Are you sure you virtual host is working fine? Have you tried to serve it without virtual hostname so you can ge it on `localhost/projectname/public/guests`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried in another browser, Virtual host is working properly.

Comment: Should I declare any routes in web.php to work?

Comment: `server IP address could not be found` doesn't sound like Laravel issue to me. I would check server logs

Comment: In postman console its show this error `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.hotelplex.test api.hotelplex.test:80
Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers'

Comment: Have you tried looking at `php artisan route:list` to ensure that the routes have registered as you expect them to?

Comment: your url should be http://api.hotelplex.dev/api/guests.

Answer (score 1):

You should just insert /api/ in the url.
Eg `http://api.hotelplex.dev/api/guests`

This is a default feature in laravel to map all the routes in routes/api.php to have /api/ prepended.

You can disable or change the word "api" changing it inside `RouteServiceProvider.php`,
by editing this function

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

to something like:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('my_custom_prefix')
         ->middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```